# How to open Angular Server?

Tags: angular

I try to install angular on my laptop. In the end of installation, when I want to start the server, I have error in the emulator.

Please could you help me to fix that ?
In attach image file.

[image]

Comment: How did you installed it?

Answer (score 0):

Try `npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular`

Also try to delete everything and clear cache and try to install again